# Is Java assertion a global runtime option or can be partially applied?

Tags: java, jvm, assert, application-server

I want to enable assertion in testing application server, but AS host deployments from another teams and my decision can conflict with them...

Quick web search show that assertion for Jboss can be enabled as global option:

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Enabling+assertions

so setting become in effect to all deployments.

Is it possible to enable assertion partially? Based on class loader (applicable for deployments in application servers) or package/class name patterns? Or other?

My question not about JBoss but in general for JVM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable):

> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the
>   -enableassertions, or -ea, switch. To disable assertions at various granularities, use the -disableassertions, or -da, switch. You specify
>   the granularity with the arguments that you provide to the switch:

Note that page contains examples directly following the above quote.

I don't think that you can make these changes *per-classloader* (as you ask above). Note however that you can [programatically set the default assertion status per classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/6jgp65ikr/index.html#assert-9). Note sure that helps you in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do that. Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable.

Comment: Your link show how to use asserts per package/class name pattern. How about per classloader?

Comment: For classloader, as Brian mentioned you can only do it programatically.